# It's given $ABCD$ an isosceles trapezioid with $A(2,6,-3,9),\, B(4,4,7,3),\, C(8,2,7,-1)$, $AB||CD$, find $D$.

Tags: geometry, vectors, euclidean-geometry, solution-verification

The problem is taken from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3739053).

> It's given $ABCD$ an isosceles trapeziois with $A:=(2,6,-3,9)$, $B:=(4,4,7,3)$, $C:=(8,2,7,-1)$, $AB||CD$, $\angle C=\angle D=60^\circ$, find $D$.

I want to present at least $3$ different solutions, so the post may appear rather lengthy.

The common part:
Let's make sure $\angle B=120^\circ$:
$$\cos\angle B=\frac{
\overrightarrow{BA}\cdot \overrightarrow{BC}
}{
|\overrightarrow{BA}|\cdot |\overrightarrow{BC}|
}=-\frac12$$
[image]

---

Let $X\in CD$, $|CX|=|CB|$ then $\triangle CBX$ is equilateral, $BADX$ is a parallelogram, thus 
$$\overrightarrow{CD}=
\frac{|\overrightarrow{BC}|}{|\overrightarrow{BA}|}
\overrightarrow{BA}+\overrightarrow{BA}$$
$$D=\left(\frac{|B-C|}{|B-A|}+1\right)(B-A)+C=(5, 5, -8, 8)$$

---

Let line $CB$: $Y=yB+(1-y)C$ and $Y$ be the intersection of the line $CB$ with perpendicular bisector hyperplane of $AB$: $(Y-\frac{B+A}{2})\cdot
\overrightarrow{BA}=0$. Combining this together we find $y$ and thus $Y$:
$$\left(yB+(1-y)C-\frac{B+A}{2}\right)\cdot(A-B)=0$$
$$y(B-C)\cdot(A-B)=-\left(C-\frac{B+A}{2}\right)\cdot(A-B)$$
$$y=-\frac{\left(C-\frac{B+A}{2}\right)\cdot(A-B)}{(B-C)\cdot(A-B)}$$
$$y=3\hbox{ and }Y=(-4, 8, 7, 11)$$
Because $\triangle YCD$ is equilateral, $YC=YD$ and
$$\overrightarrow{YD}=
\frac{|\overrightarrow{YC}|}{|\overrightarrow{YA}|}\overrightarrow{YA}$$
$$D=\frac{|\overrightarrow{YC}|}{|\overrightarrow{YA}|}\overrightarrow{YA}+Y=
(5, 5, -8, 8)$$

---

Now let $D$ ob the line, parallel to $AB$, passing through $C$: 
$D=C+t(A-B)$. Let's use $\angle ADC=60^\circ$ directly:
$$\cos \angle ADC=
\frac{
\overrightarrow{DA}\cdot\overrightarrow{DC}
}{
|\overrightarrow{DA}|\cdot|\overrightarrow{DC}|
}=
\frac{(C+t(A-B)-A)\cdot(t(A-B))}{
|C+t(A-B)-A|\cdot|t(A-B)|
}=\\
\frac{(C+t(A-B)-A)\cdot(A-B)}{
|C+t(A-B)-A|\cdot|(A-B)|
}=\frac{1}{2}$$
Performing multiplications and lengths as square roots of squares of corresponding vectors, we get 
$$\frac{36\cdot(-5 + 4t)}{6\sqrt{7 - 10t + 4t^2}\cdot 12}=\frac{1}{2},$$
squaring, rearranging and solving for $t$ we get 
$$3 - 5t + 2t^2=0$$
$$t=\frac{3}{2}$$
(the other root corresponds to $-5 + 4t\lt 0$). Thus
$$D=C+t(A-B)=(5, 5, -8, 8)$$
Not tired yet?) The fourth solution:

---

Again let $D=C+t(A-B)$ and the perpendicular bisector of $AB$ be 
$\mathbf{n}\cdot\left(\mathbf{x}-\frac{A+B}{2}\right)=0$ where $\mathbf{n}=B-A$. Then, for symmetry relative to the perpendicular bisector, we get
$$\mathbf{n}\cdot\left(A-\frac{A+B}{2}\right)=-
\mathbf{n}\cdot\left(B-\frac{A+B}{2}\right),\\ 
\mathbf{n}\cdot\left(C-\frac{A+B}{2}\right)=-
\mathbf{n}\cdot\left(D-\frac{A+B}{2}\right)$$
plugging $D$ into the latter equation we get a linear with respect to $t$, solving we get $t=\frac{3}{2}$ again.

All the numbers conputations are [here](https://tio.run/##ZVHLboMwELzzFUi92GDjYqK0BfkXqko5oYhKtktaJB4NOJFQxLfThRCHqBd71juzs@utpPnJK2kKLcdRxuLCyZbQiLwNiYJoQzbkhURDoiF4JRwCGg6Jo4AqqUqUFhou50nW32XunvO2OEApUzS189EWtdkrGSjN3pu2ApgtQGeZ89Q15WkiuuFC1T66pa3AD7EH14rN3fx4ujr0XSx2TXnO96j3lI9C2mNPU6R8iRnHgZJCPJNLP2TJYtF3mZPGYsW@ZVKXBS6kkwer3uljQRF6KIoZQorqGdrC1iK1aJ5B03SZRgLyEJzYTx9sIqc@VTBJUf2WxaHfI@2biagwlTiYga0JTMBfeR2uBLtja2bVXbQKMiueZFc1j8XSk1pnuQ3uzYAji7b4k9OQbTw01WBTOEM@w8mhM3YX/9u/fsDq3X6JyoQIGScXc19SZyy0kmk78D6Ofw).

---

@jiten's solution from the comment (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3739053/find-coordinates-of-point-in-mathbbr4/3739095#comment7716150_3739095) (I didn't quite get it):

> Q.4 image, need coord. point $p$ in trapezoid with: A$(2,6,-3,9)$, B$(4,4,7,3)$, C$(8,2,7,-1)$, p$(x, y, z, w)$.
> DV line BA$<-2, 2, -10, 6>$.
> Param. form point on line $r(t)= (4,4,7,3) + t(-2, 2, -10, 6) = (4-2t, 4+2t, 7-10t, 3 +6t), t\in \mathbb{R}$.
> Also, for line pC $r_1(t) = (8,2,7,-1) + s(-2, 2, -10, 6) = (8-2s, 2+2s, 7-10s, 3 +6s), s\in \mathbb{R}$;
> with $s=1$ for vertex p $(8-2s, 2+2s, 7-10s, 3 +6s)\implies (6, 4, -3, 9)$.
> Need verify by addl eqns. Say, find intersection lines Ap, Cp; with DV line Cp $= <x-8, y-2, z-7, w +1>$, of line Ap $=<x-2, y-6, z+3, w-9>$. But, not working.